# Regex pattern to find all strings which contain at most 3 alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am new to regular expressions and the `re` module in python. I wanted to form a regex pattern which helps in identifying all strings which contain at most three alphanumeric characters. Some example patterns which I want to find are :

```
gut
ok
aa
na
N/A
x
c
Nil
wu
No.
E
A
I
k k
H
o
K
N
Y
Top
OK了
m
| yes
N/A |
t | T
t | T
| idk
| wsq
t | T
ｂ | n
```

I have prepared a regex pattern `^[^a-zA-Z\d]*([^\n]){0,3}[^a-zA-Z\d]*$` but it fails if we have a special character in between 2 alphanumeric characters.

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 3):

You might repeat 1-3 times any char except chars a-z or a digit followed by a single char a-z 0-9.

If you don't want to cross newlines, you can add those to the negated character class.

```
^[^a-zA-Z\d\r\n]*(?:[a-zA-Z\d][^a-zA-Z\d\r\n]*){1,3}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^a-zA-Z\d\r\n]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except a-z, a digit or newline
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `[a-zA-Z\d]` Match a single char a-z or a digit
  - `[^a-zA-Z\d\r\n]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except a-z, a digit or newline
- `){1,3}` Close the group and repeat 1-3 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vruxwJ/1)

Or a bit shorter using an inline modifier for case insensitive matching:

```
(?i)^[^a-z\d\r\n]*(?:[a-z\d][^a-z\d\r\n]*){1,3}$
```

Comment: Hey thanks. This worked on all cases I wanted to cover. I just wanted to know, is there a way I can include the cases where text contains only spaces, only special characters or a mixture of spaces and special characters and detect them as well?

Comment: @SounakRay You can extend the character classes with the characters that you want to allow https://regex101.com/r/RjdMkW/1

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that next to 3 alpha-chars at most, you'd want at least one. In that case you may want to try:

```
(?i)^(?!(?:.*[a-z]){4})(?:.*[a-z].*){1,3}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cdpe6R/1)

- `(?i)` - Inline modifier to match remainder case-insensitive.
- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?!(?:.*[a-z]){4})` - Negative lookahead with (4x) nested non-capture group matching any char other than newline 0+ times and an alpha char.
- `(?:.*[a-z].*){1,3}` - Non-capture group (1-3x) to match 0+ chars other than newline, an alpha char, and again 0+ chars other than newline.
- `$` - End line anchor.

---

If you are up for some alternative way you could also use `re.findall()` and count the matches found:

```
import re
s = 'N/A'
cnt = len(re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]', s))
if cnt > 0 and cnt < 4:
    print('Valid')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

Comment: That also works :-) (You might also use a negation `[^a-z\n]*[a-z]` instead of `.*[a-z]` to prevent some backtracking)